# Module loads with PhantomJS but not with Chrome Headless during Karma Angularjs testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine, google-chrome-headless

```
[$injector:nomod] Module 'XXX' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

- the module is clearly loaded in karma.conf.js in the correct order
- it's the only module that doesn't load out of many and in 2000 unit tests fails only 12 cases
- **works with phantomjs doesn't work on chrome**

What can be the reason?